# How to fix error: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FOR'

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I'm new to the PIVOT function and so far I could not run any query successfully while pivoting a table.

Here's the data source:

```
region         countries
Africa         180
Antarctica     3
Asia           99
Europe         154
Middle East    54
North America  123
Oceania        87
South America  48
```

I need each region to become a column - only one row with the count of countries in the region.

Compatibility level: SQL Server 2019 (150)

I tried every suggestion I could find online but still can't understand what I am doing wrong.

```
SELECT [Africa], [Asia], [Middle East], [North America], 
       [Oceania], [South America], [Antarctica]
FROM (
  SELECT region, count(name) as countries
  FROM dbo.country
  Group by region
) AS pDataSource
PIVOT
(
 countries
    FOR region IN ([Africa], [Asia], [Middle East], [North America], 
    [Oceania], [South America], [Antarctica])
) AS pPivotTable
```

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 10
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FOR'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the aggregation  notice the `sum(countries)`

```
...
PIVOT
(
 sum(countries) 
    FOR region IN ([Africa], [Asia], [Middle East], [North America], 
    [Oceania], [South America], [Antarctica])
) AS pPivotTable
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use conditional aggregation?

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN region = 'Africa' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Africa,
       SUM(CASE WHEN region = 'Asia' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Asia,
       . . .   -- continue for the rest of the continents
FROM dbo.country;
```

Comment: Thanks, Gordon, that works great.
However, I'm trying to learn to use the PIVOT function and don't understand what's wrong with the query...
My objective would eventually be to have a table of all countries by continent - do you see any workaround?